Защита от SQL-инъекций в динамических запросах Postgres
Есть огромная view, которая через UNION ALL объединяет с добрую сотню подзапросов, которые тянут данные, нарушающие правила качества данных. Есть желание вместо этого забить подзапросы в таблицу в виде текста и прогонять их в пакете как динамические. Плюсы подхода довольно очевидны (проще деплоить, работать параллельно, отслеживать версии и т.д.), но и минусы есть. И больше всего в рамках вопроса беспокоят SQL-инъекции.
Ситуация:

Злоумышленник нашел способ вставить свой SQL-код в таблицу с подзапросами для правил
Пакет выполняется под могущественным пользователем, а другого создать не дадут (но можно создать роль).

Как ограничить функционально пакета так чтобы он мог лишь селектить? Очевидно, можно регулярными выражениями проверить подзапрос на ключевые слова, но хочется чего-то более надежного.

Шел 2024 год, разрабы всех СУБД не добавили валидатор текста запроса отдельным пакетом или какая-нибудь возможность запускать динамический запрос с конкретным набором привилегий.

А обязательно ли хранить эти части-запросы в таблице? Создайте по view на каждую часть, и поместите их все в отдельную схему.

@PavelMayorov я так подозреваю, однажды действительно дойдет до того, что вьюху придется рубить если не на сотню, то хоть на несколько, когда запрос начнет кушать слишком много ресурсов. Он в одном окружении уже не вывез в оперативе всё держать и начал на диск писать, замедлившись раз в 100. Но отдельная схема и сотни вьюх не вариант всё-таки, иначе можно было бы  просто юзера со слабыми правами сделать, который при всё желании не мог бы навредить попытавшись выполнить вредоносную инъекцию :)

А нужна ли именно вьюха? И как часто она собственно меняется?

@CrazyElf, меняется она регулярно. Именно вьюха не нужна, как я и сказал выше, я бы хотел подзапросы прогонять в пакете. Просто это достаточно простой способ повысить секурность и избежать инъекций, поэтому Древние, видимо, решили поступить таким способом. Но сейчас она слишком разрослась и хотелось бы это порешать. Но без снижения секурности.

@ВиталийЯндулов а почему не вариант? Получить список всех вьюх в схеме, если что, достаточно легко. Ну и по поводу прав - почему бы и правда не сделать отдельного пользователя со слабыми правами?

@PavelMayorov потому что в реальной жизни мы не всегда свободные художники, а порой весьма подневольные птицы) Особенно, если базой рулит подрядчик, поверх продукта которого вы прикостылили свой, а шерудить внутри тебя пускают по блату и под очень честное слово)

В JDBC драйвере можно при соединении указать сессии режим readonly https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/use/ Если ты не JDBC используешь, то может в твоём драйвере это тоже поддерживается?
